# Python3 - Create a comma separated table without creating a csv file from two lists

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to print a comma separated table from two lists l1 & l2

- Without creating a new csv file
- Without opening an existing csv file

How can this easily be done?
Just want to print it, no csv file manipulation.

```
l1 = ["John","Mark","Chuck"]
l2 = [30, 40, 50]
```

**Wished output**

```
Name,Age <-- Headers
John,30
Mark,40
Chuck,50
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:-

```
l1 = ["John","Mark","Chuck"]
l2 = [30, 40, 50]

print( "Name", "Age") 
for i in zip( l1, l2 ):
    print( i[0], ',', i[1] )
```

Do ask for clarification if required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to print them you could do something like this:

```py
l1 = ["John","Mark","Chuck"]
l2 = [30, 40, 50]

# create a new list that includes the headers
new_l1 = ["Name", *l1]
new_l2 = ["Age", *l2]

# loop through both lists using zip()
for name, age in zip(new_l1, new_l2):
    print(f"{name},{age}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a dictionary would solve your problem. Just put the keys in and set the values that correspond to them. In your case, it would go like this:

```
dictionary = {
  "John, ": 30,
  "Mark, ": 40,
  "Chuck, ": 50
}

print("Name | Age")
for key, value in dictionary.items():
  print(f"{key} {value}")
```

Output:

```
Name | Age
John,  30
Mark,  40
Chuck,  50
```

Tell me if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'zip' to merge the two lists together, as others have already suggested.  Or you can use a simple for loop to do this.

```
>>> l1 = ['John', 'Mark', 'Chuck']
>>> l2 = [30, 40, 50 ]
>>> for i in range(len(l1)):
    print("{},{}".format(l1[i],l2[i]))
    
John,30
Mark,40
Chuck,50
```